# Database Connection error while connecting MySQL through Python

Tags: python, mysql, connection

```
import mysql.connector
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

No matter how many commands I fire, it is still showing this error and I have not named my file as mysql.py

Please tell me which version I need to install

Comment: Then you haven't installed mysql connector properly.

Comment: Install mysql connector properly, `pip install mysql-connector-python`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jish I ran that command but it didn't work

Comment: What is the error you are getting when run the `pip install` command?

Comment: Can you go to the terminal and input `pip list` & show us the results?